# i have to trigger parent div when i click on any child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my html code: if i click any child div inside demo class it has trigger parent id i.e(id:1,2,3,....).

```
<div class="click">

    <div class="category-list demo" id="1" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="category-name">
            technology
        </div>
        <div class="category-progress">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div>
    <section class="timeline" id="a"></section>
    <section class="timeline" id="b"></section>
    <section class="timeline" id="c"></section>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelector('.click').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      var id=e.target.id;
      var val=Number(id);
      if(val===NaN){
        console.log(val); 

      }
    else{
        currentDiv(val);      
          console.log("Number:"+val);

    }
    });
};
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);


function showDivs(n) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline");
    console.log("X value:"+x.length);
    console.log("N value:"+n);
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  

  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" btn-warning", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
     console.log("x Array:"+x[slideIndex-1].style.display);
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " ";

}

});
```

i face a problem that if click on category-name (or)category-progress  it is showing id=0 but i have get parent id i.e 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery for this

```
  $(".click").click(function(event){
    var parentId = $(event.currentTarget).closest('div.category-list').attr('id');
    console.log(parentId);
  });
```

or

```
  $(".click").click(function(event){
    var parentId = $(event.currentTarget).parent().attr('id');
    console.log(parentId);
  });
```

and just add your `click` selector to your child divs.

```
<div class="category-list demo" id="1" data-dismiss="modal">
    <div class="category-name click">
        technology
    </div>
    <div class="category-progress click">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please be sure to set sign this question as completed by clicking the mark

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you click over `technbology` or `70% Complete` text, the `target` that the event is catching is a DivElement for 'technology' and SpanElement for `70% Complete`, so when you try to get de ID with 'var id=e.target.id;' you are not position in the element with the id attribute you are in their child.

To fix this you haven't got to use the parent DivElement with class `click` if recommended to use class `category-list` for example because you want to get the ids where you click in the list.

Change the `QuerySelector` for '.category-list':

```
document.querySelector('.category-list').addEventListener('click',
```

Change the way that get de id attribute:

With jQuery:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

With Pure Javascript:

```
var id = this.getAttribute("id")
```

You can use any solution, jQuery or Pure JS.

The complete solution:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelector('.category-list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      var id=$(this).attr('id');
      var val=Number(id);
      if(val===NaN){
        console.log(val); 

      }
    else{
        currentDiv(val);      
          console.log("Number:"+val);

    }
    });
};
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);


function showDivs(n) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline");
    console.log("X value:"+x.length);
    console.log("N value:"+n);
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  

  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" btn-warning", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
     console.log("x Array:"+x[slideIndex-1].style.display);
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " ";

}

});
```